# Union shortcut for 2 columns of table and identical query?

Tags: mysql, sql

So imagine a table that consists of first, middle and last names.

I want to write a query that, returns all the middle and first names, as 1 column, of people whose last name presents an entirely arcane, complicated quality that requires 20 nested subqueries or so to determine.

One way to do that is

```
Select FirstName From Names Where LastName in (HISTSNEROIP)
Union
Select MiddleName From Names Where LastName in (HISTSNEROIP)
```

Where HISTSNEROIP stands for 'huge inefficient subquery that should not even run once if possible'. As the name would imply, running it twice as above is a big no-no.

Ideally, I would do something like

```
Select FirstName and MiddleName from names where Lastname in (HISTSNEROIP)
```

Where 'and' is replaced by whatever tool eludes me.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: v8.0.15 of mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work..

```
SELECT f_m 
FROM (
    SELECT FirstName as f_m, LastName FROM names
    UNION 
    SELECT MiddleName as f_m, LastName FROM names
) as T
WHERE T.LastName in (HISTSNEROIP);
```

Comment: This. This is so ingeniously, gloriously simple I feel stupid not having thought about it.

Comment: No worries! happens with all of us . Glad it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html):

```
with cte (
  HISTSNEROIP
)
select firstname from names where lastname in cte
union all
select middlename from names where lastname in cte
```

This way HISTSNEROIP runs only once.

Comment: Welp, love the answer, but it turns out the server's sql version is lower than my client's. No CTE for me! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you select  this in one query?

```
Select FirstName, MiddleName
From Names
Where LastName in (HISTSNEROIP)
```

If you need, you can unpivot this:

```
Select (case when x.n = 1 then FirstName else MiddleName end)
From Names n cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n) x
Where LastName in (HISTSNEROIP)
```

Comment: I need a single column of names, first or middle. 

And, we have a dumb policy about avoiding flow control where possible. My higher ups would probably prefer 20 executions of HISTSNEROIP to using it...

Comment: @ThanosMaravel . . . The second solution provides a single list of names.

Comment: I know, but it has 'case', which counts as flow control for said dumb policy.